# Rails database performance tuning

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, performance, indexing

I'm working a lot with a VERY large mysql2 database at the moment, and although I have indexed what I thought were the proper fields, the return time for some queries is quite slow.

I have two models that are causing issues, `Comment` and `Commenter`.

Now, there is a `has_many` relationship between `Commenter` and `Comment`, but my query relies on finding the each Comment's Commenter's username. So I'll run something like this:

```
c = Blog.first.comments ##this bit runs fine, I indexed the "blog_id" field on Comments
c.collect {|c| c.commenter.username}
```

To help with the speed issues, I created an index on the `commenter_id` field for the Comment model. But it is still running very slow..

Does anybody know of what I could do differently, that would help increase the speed of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using eager load, which is not the link RaskolnikOFF posted, but the rails-cast before it, http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading (still gave you an upvote for driving me to the answer)

Apparently what I was looking for was the following:

```
b = Blog.find(:first, :include=>{:comments => :commenter})
b.comments.collect {|c| c.commenter.username}
```

The first line loads the first blog and all of its relations (and returns the blog). So when I call the second line, everything is already loaded and waiting to be accessed..

Which works way better than what I was originally doing.

Answer (score 3):

An index on `commenter_id` helps when you want to find the comments for a given `commenter_id` ("find me all the comments joe made").

But when you do `c.commenter` you're searching for users, presumably the one whose `id` is equal to the comment's `commenter_id`. There should already be an index on the `id` column. The surefire way is to take the actual sql statements generated (in development these are in development.log), and use explain on them, for example

```
explain select * from comments where id = 12345
```

Given that it's very unlikely that you managed to create a table without an index on it's `id` column, the most likely culprit is eager loading - if a post had 500 comments then the above code would fetch the associated users one by one, and those 500 roundtrips to the database add up

```
c.includes(:commenter).collect {...}
```

or

```
c.eager_load(:commenter).collect {...}
```

will fix that (the above snippets assume you're using rails 3).

Comment: I believe eager_load and includes work for only active record relations. Not arrays, and in my post, c is an array.

Comment: It's not actually - associations are relations - you can definitely do filtered_ordered_comments = some_blog.comments.where(...).order(...) for example

Answer (score 2):

Collect is going to load ActiveRecord objects for every commenter with all fields one at a time. Including / Eager Loading will load them with one query which will help with speed, but if you want the absolute best performance and you just need the names you're better off reaching down to SQL more directly with something to the tune of:

```
c         = Blog.first.comments
user_ids  = c.collect(&:commenter_id)
usernames = Commenter.where(['commenter_id IN (?)',user_ids]).select('username').collect(&:username)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do too much unnecessary queries here
 `c.collect {|c| c.commenter.username}`
 I think eager loading can help you. Watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?autoplay=true